# VxWorks on TI Launchpad Boards

Tags: arm, texas-instruments, rtos, cortex-m4

I am trying to find out if VxWorks will be able to run on something similar to the TI EK-TM4C123GXL board (http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-connected-ek-tm4c123gxl.html). It looks like Cortex M4 is supported but I'm not sure what else needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even want to run an RTOS on such a simple part?  I'm sure TI has plenty of examples and libraries to abstract the tougher peripherals.  TI also has its own RTOS if it is really necessary.

More specific to your question, besides checking if the core processor is supported you would ideally need to know if VxWorks has "board" support for that eval kit or at least specific support for that part or device family.  If not, you'll be spending a bunch of time writing drivers to use the peripherals (like CAN or USB).  I would ask them directly if they support that chip family and/or eval kit.

Answer (score 0):

You must search board support package (BSP) of this RTOS.I think there are BSP for some other families from TI like Sitara or hercules but not sure about mentioned one.check windriver's website.